# ConnectApiException:[errorCode=INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS] Channel: LWR Enhanced Experience Cloud site

Tags: apex, community, experience-cloud, lwr, digital-experience-bundle

I am using the LWR Enhanced Experience cloud site and configured the Digital Experience app. Created a workspace and added a few images to it. Now after I select the image am accessing the image as shown in this video:- https://youtu.be/QmfCglNURIY?feature=shared

```
ConnectApi.ManagedContentVersionCollection contentCollection = ConnectApi.ManagedContent.getManagedContentByContentKeys(
            networkId,
            new List<String>{ contentId },
            0,
            1,
            language,
            filterby,
            false
        );
        return contentCollection.items[0].contentNodes;
```

I get this error message in Apex:- ConnectApiException:[errorCode=INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS]: You don't have access to this channel.

How do I provide access to the channel for internal users and guest users so that it can access the image?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you found any solution to this problem?